# JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC [windows]

Tags: java, bouncycastle

Hi I found this question several times on stackoverflow but none of those covers the following question:

I am normally creating a spring-boot fat jar with bouncy-castle within the BOOT-INF/lib directory. Everything runs fine if I execute the jar on a **linux** system. But if I execute it under **windows** I get the infamous error:

```
error constructing MAC: java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
java.io.IOException: error constructing MAC: java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
```

Since it does only happen on windows I would guess that the file-encoding has something to do with it but I was not able to change it package the spring-boot jar in a windows style. Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this problem for windows systems?

Comment: Jar files are not different on Windows. Are you maybe using OpenJDK on Linux (often supplied by distro) but Oracle Java on Windows (not supplied by MS)? Oracle Java requires cryptoproviders for some functions (including MAC) be signed with a cert issued by Sun-now-Oracle, while OpenJDK does not. And if either your JRE or your bcprov jar is old it may cause problems because the original Sun CA cert expired and was replaced.

Comment: Thats a pretty good thing to keep in mind. But that's unfortunately not it. I am using Oracle JDK 17 and 11 here. Both in newest versions.